# Check the convergence of a sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $X$ =$[0,1]$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|/(1+|x-y|)$ be the metric defined on $X$. Then check whether the sequence ${x_n = 1/n^2}$

A) Converges in $(X,d)$

B)Does not converge in $(X,d)$

My attempt :

I was trying to use the fact that if, $dist(z,${$x_n$ |n $\in$ S}$)$ =0, (for $z \in X$) for every infinite subset $S$ of $N$ then the sequence is convergent in $X$.

So when i applied the metric i got,

$d(0,1/n^2)$ = $1/(1+n^2)$ which would always be greater than zero and hence its infimum would also always be greater than zero,and hence using the definition given above i concluded that the given sequence does not converge in $(X,d)$.

Am i correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are not. The infimum of a set $X$ of positive numbers may be zero. Example:

1. $X=(0,\infty)$
2. $X=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
3. $X=\{1/(1+n^2):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

The infimum of all those sets is $0$, but $0\not\in X$. The sets have an infimum but not a minimum.